# Java Eclipse launch problems

Tags: java, eclipse

```
!SESSION 2014-07-11 21:28:10.330          ----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=unknown
    java.version=1.7.0_60
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
    Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse 4 0 2014-07-11 21:28:16.695
!MESSAGE Unable to load parent configuration from: C:\Program Files     (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\configuration\org.eclipse.update\platform.xml


-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
--C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\javaw.exe
launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

I am trying to start using eclipse again on my new computer and am running into more problems then i remember. I have downloaded eclipse from their website and when ever i go to run eclipse.exe the logo flashes and nothing happens. I posted the .log file and my eclipse.ini file because when scanning for answers the problem seemed to lie therefor most people. I am not getting any type of error message on screen. I also manually added the -vm line with mypath because eclipses website said to try that. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eclipse.buildId=unknown` looks immediately suspicious, but first of all, do not unpack Eclipse into the "Program Files" directory. Put it somewhere where your login has complete and sole ownership.

Comment: Eclipse is on my desktop my program files contains javaw.exe

Comment: Which file did you download and are you just double-clicking on `eclipse.exe`?

Comment: I downloaded a zip folder called eclipsse esclipse its the java developer one I unzipped it to my desktop I opened the folder where theres lots of other files and I double clicked eclipse.exe thats what there tutorial said

Comment: I uninstalled java and reinstalled it then reinstalled eclipse that got it to work thank you for your help